# Add RAM to HP-UX

Tags: memory, hp-ux

I need to add some RAM to a machine running HP-UX.

Is there anything that I need to do before or after adding the physical RAM? Or will the OS just recognize the RAM and no further tasks needed.

I've never worked with HP-UX before, so I just need to know if there is anything with the OS that I need to do to before, or after adding the physical memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OS will pick it up automatically, but applications may be configured to used limited amounts (this isn't very normal, but entirely possible). You'll need to review the configuration, or at least monitor the box after the upgrade to be sure the additional RAM is having the desired effect.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.

Yes I plan to do some monitoring after. I have also check some commands to display the physical memory in HP-UX OS

Comment: Work is done without any problem.

No need to change anything on the server. 

Thank You

Answer (score 3):

You might want to check to ensure that there is a sufficient amount of swap space allocated to support the new memory configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Before adding the physical RAM you need to check the quickspecs of your server to identify supported configuration of DIMM.
For instance in superdome quick specs there is a list of supported DIMM configuration.

Comment: What do the physical requirements of the RAM have to do with configuring the OS to use new RAM?

Comment: They depends from your HP-UX server model. Check the physical requirements in the quick specs and release notes documents of your server model.